Is there a way to import Vue and also export it as a global var
I am developing a Vue-based component library/framework (Vue 3, Typescript, Vite), but I do not want to externalize Vue dependency as what Vite documentation is suggesting (Libary Mode).
The reason is that some clients using our library will be working purely with templates - they just write html (with vue syntax) that will be interpreted as some component template at runtime. They do not have a web development build toolchain set up, and has no idea what is npm, package.json, or vite etc. And we would like to keep it that way.
Now in order to support that, either we externalize Vue and they have to include the IIFE build of Vue in their index.html, or we bundle Vue but somehow still expose its full capability (e.g. no treeshaking).
What I am not sure is how to include the full Vue in the bundle without treeshaking even though the library code we write might only depend on a small subset of the features of Vue.

You could probably look into using the Vue compiler on the HTML received by your clients.

It can be as simple as import * as Vue from 'vue'; window.Vue = Vue, however it's not obvious you need to expose "Vue" specifically.

@kissu that is indeed what I am doing. Basically I need to include the full build of Vue to have the template compiler bundled. The library's components are pre-compiled so the runtime complier capability will not be exercised during library's build time. But I need to retain that capability at runtime as I am going to receive string based templates.

@EstusFlask is it really the same as e.g. using the IIFE build of Vue? I know the IIFE build exposes the Vue on the global object, I am just not sure if that Vue will be any different from the Vue imported through import * as Vue from 'vue'. In particular, will such an import statement sufficient to ensure no part of Vue is tree-shaked? And nothing that shouldnt be minified wont be minified?

Imported "Vue" cannot be tree-shaken if it's already used in the project, it's not necessary to explicitly do something with it. Whether you need  window.Vue = depends on the need to access it in other places on the page. It's pretty much the same as loading vue.global.js. Consider explaining how exactly the lib is intended to be used, with code examples, this will shed some light
